# Mockito with Scala, any matcher resolved with multiple implementations

Tags: scala, mockito

In our Scala project we use Mockito for testing purposes.

An **annoying** issue we have is that while using `any` matcher, it's always in `can't resolve symbol any` although it's not affect the code in builds or runtime.

There are two `any` implementation in Mockito (2.12):

```
  def any[T](implicit evidence$11 : scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) : T = { /* compiled code */ }
  def any[T]() : T = { /* compiled code */ }
```

How can we "help" Mockito understand what `any` he should use?

For example:
[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: Does `ArgumentMatchers.any[UserGuild]` work (importing `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers`)?

Comment: When I stating explicitly `ArgumentMatchers.any[UserGuild]` it does help. Once I'm trying to `import all members...` it fails again.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of self promotion but I just published a library called `mockito-scala` that solves this issue and many more, is part of the mockito ecosystem so hopefully should become the default when working with Scala, you can find it here https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala with the information to get the dependency and what problems does it actually solves.

The syntax for the matcher is improved, in particular `any` now solves the correct type and it drops the parentheses so it reads better

Answer (score 2):

Double check your `build.sbt` contains

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % Test
```

and you have the following import in your test file:

```
import org.mockito.Matchers.any
```

Here is a minimal working snippet (assuming ScalaTest):

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito.when
import org.mockito.Matchers.any

class CalculatorTest extends FunSuite with MockitoSugar {
  test("calculator add method") {
    val calcMock = mock[Calculator]
    when(calcMock.add(any[Int], any[Int])).thenReturn(10)
    assert(calcMock.add(7, 3) == 10)
  }
}
```

where `trait Calculator { def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int }`

Comment: If using IntelliJ, try `sbt projects tool window | Refresh your project`. Also try `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart`